# how can iterate over an array of array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a list as below:

```
order = [
  {term: 201, x: 2},
  {term: 201, y: 7},
  {term: 201, z: 2},
  {term: 202, a: 3},
  {term: 202, b: 4},
  {term: 202, c: 0}
]
```

how can I get this result?

```
[
  {term: 201, x: 2, y: 7, z: 2},
  {term: 202, a: 3, b: 4, c: 0},
]
```

Comment: Please show some effort. You need to iterate over your existing hashes and merge them when values under their `term` keys are equal

Comment: order.each do |a|     a.each do |h|        h.each do |k,v|                             need to do something here

Comment: You are getting marked down because you don't say what your requirements are, other than "i want this result from this data".  You should have said something like "I want one hash in the results for each value of `term`, which groups together all the values of the hashes with that value for `term`", or something else if this isn't what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `group_by` method :

```
order.group_by { |h| h[:term] }
     .map { |_, v| v.inject(:update) }
# => [{:term=>201, :x=>2, :y=>7, :z=>2}, {:term=>202, :a=>3, :b=>4, :c=>0}]
```

- group small hashes by their term number.
- Then iterate over each group of small hashes.
- While iterating merge all the small hashes to make a single one.